# calling function that returns rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11

I think I understand most of the rvalue stuff, but when I tried to implement the following code, I got segmentation fault(core dumped) :( maybe I'm still missing some details and would appreciate any help!

I have this `struct Mode` in my header:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Mode
{
    explicit Mode(const int id_in, const int p_val=1) : id{id_in}, p{new int{p_val}} {
        std::cout << "explicit param default ctr called..." << std::endl;

    }
    Mode() : id{42}, p{nullptr}{
        std::cout << "default ctr called..." << std::endl;
    }

    Mode&& clone() {
        Mode m(*this);
        m.p.reset(new int{*m.p});
        return std::move(m);
    }   
    int id;
    std::shared_ptr<int> p;
};
```

and in main.cpp I do this:

```
int main()
{
    Mode m{42, 43};
    Mode m2;
    m2 = m.clone();

    cout << m.p << endl;
    cout << m2.p;
}
```

what happens in detail in the line `m2 = m.clone()`? What I understand so far is: in `clone()` it creates a temporary copy of `m` using the copy constructor `Mode m(*this)`, and std::move the contents of this temp object, and finally returns to its caller `m2`. And in main.cpp I assign the rvalue to `m2` using move assignment? I'm not so sure till this step...

Comment: gcc would warn you about redundancy in `return std::move(m);`. If you return a local variable, just return it as is, without a rvalue reference, and let the compiler optimize the return value, it does that really well

Comment: It should be `Mode clone()` and `return m;`

Answer (score 2):

You code has undefined behavior.

You're binding the local variable `m` to the rvalue-reference returned; the local variable would be destroyed when the function returns, so what it returns is always a dangled reference.

> and `std::move` the contents of this temp object

You might be misunderstanding `std::move`; it just converts the argument to rvalue, but won't perform move operation in fact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That makes sense. My motivation was, if Mode is a very large data struct, and I just return as is, like mentioned by @Geoffroy and M.M, wouldn't it be inefficient as I make a copy again while returning? How does the compiler optimize it? And is there a better way to deal with it?

Comment: @Mr.787 Yes, what Geoffroy and M.M suggested is the best idea; [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) will help you.